# How to display data from API to flutter Multi Select Form Field

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, multi-select, rest

I am using this [Package](https://pub.dev/packages/multiselect_formfield) for the Multi-Select form Field in Flutter. In this Package already defined data source like

```
                    {
                      "display": "Running",
                      "value": "Running",
                    },
                    {
                      "display": "Climbing",
                      "value": "Climbing",
                    },
                    {
                      "display": "Walking",
                      "value": "Walking",
                    },
                  ],
```

But, I want Directly load contents in API How to integrate it

Answer (score 0):

Make a map with display and value after retrieving the data from API and pass that map to data source

Comment: Hello Bro !! Please share some demo code to do it ??